# Why does authentication not work with my ASP.NET REST API?

Tags: ios, asp.net, objective-c, rest

I setup an ASP.NET REST API, and am trying to connect through iOS. The same error continues to appear, and I am not sure where the connection is "broken". In NSLog the link appears with both slashes rather than a forward slash as is in the NSString. Can anyone show me why this is not connecting?

Completion block log:

```
2015-02-08 23:19:00.795 b2bGatewayWebview[7266:548905] Loading... ["method","interface","parameters","UserAuthentication","http:\/\/website.com\/folder\/Handler1.ashx",{"userName":"DummyAcct","passsword":"DummyPwd"}]
2015-02-08 23:19:00.796 b2bGatewayWebview[7266:548905] Loading... {"method":"Getmembers","interface":"http:\/\/website.com\/folder\/Handler1.ashx","parameters":{"username":"DummyAcct"}}
2015-02-08 23:19:00.795 b2bGatewayWebview[7266:548861] View did load called.
2015-02-08 23:19:01.525 b2bGatewayWebview[7266:548937] done
2015-02-08 23:19:01.537 b2bGatewayWebview[7266:548937] RAW response = {
  "Successful": false,
  "ErrorMessage": "Internal server error"
}
```

RestAPI.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RestAPI: UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *url;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *interface;

-(void) CreateNewAccount:(NSString*)ausername password:(NSString*)apassword completionHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSError *error))handler;

-(void) Getmembers:(NSString*)ausername completionHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSError *error))handler;

-(void) UserAuthentication:(NSString*)auserName passsword:(NSString*)apasssword completionHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSError *error))handler;

@end
```

RestAPI.m

```
#import "RestAPI.h"

@implementation RestAPI

@synthesize url;
@synthesize interface;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *initialLink = @"http://website.com/Handler1.ashx";


    [self setInterface:initialLink];

    NSString *username = @"DummyAcct";
    NSString *password = @"DummyPswd";

    //asynchronously call login method
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self UserAuthentication:username passsword:password completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Login method called.");
    }];


    [self Getmembers:username completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSError *error) {
            nil;
    }];

    });
    NSLog(@"View did load called.");

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (id) init

{

self = [super init];

if (self) {

    [self setUrl: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://website.com/Handler1.ashx"]];

    [self setInterface:@"http://website.com/Handler1.ashx"];

}

return self;

}

- (void)load:(NSData*)data completionHandler:(void(^)(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error))handler

{

    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Loading... %@", s);



    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setHTTPBody:data];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue

                           completionHandler:handler];

}


- (void) Getmembers:(NSString*)ausername completionHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSError *error))handler

{

    NSMutableDictionary *d = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [d setValue:interface forKey:@"interface"];

    [d setValue:@"Getmembers" forKey:@"method"];

    NSMutableDictionary *p = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [p setValue:ausername forKey:@"username"];

    [d setValue:p forKey:@"parameters"];



    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:d options:0 error:nil];

    [self load:data completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"done");

        NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"RAW response = %@", s);

        NSDictionary *d = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

        handler(d, error);

    }];

}

//login method
-(void) UserAuthentication:(NSString*)auserName passsword:(NSString*)apasssword completionHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSError *error))handler

{
    //NSMutableArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *d = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [d setValue:interface forKey:@"interface"];
    //[a setValue:interface forKey:@"interface"];

    [d setValue:@"UserAuthentication" forKey:@"method"];
    //[a setValue:@"UserAuthentication" forKey:@"method"];
    NSMutableDictionary *p = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [p setValue:auserName forKey:@"userName"];

    [p setValue:apasssword forKey:@"passsword"];

    [d setValue:p forKey:@"parameters"];
    //[a setValue:p forKey:@"parameters"];

    NSMutableArray *dictAllKeys=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[d allKeys]];
    NSMutableArray *dictAllValues=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[d allValues]];
    NSMutableArray *keysAndValues=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dictAllKeys arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:dictAllValues]];

    //NSJSONWritingOptions *writingOptions;
    NSError *error;
    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:keysAndValues options:0 error:&error];

    [self load:data completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"done");

        NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"RAW response = %@", s);

        //NSJSONReadingOptions *options;
        NSError *error2;
        NSDictionary *d = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error2];

        handler(d, error);

    }];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rest API SQL settings were incorrect (Integrated Security was true). Also on the iOS side, I should not have been passing an array for user authentication, but a dictionary.